# Updating user profile image along with user profile in Laravel

Tags: laravel, upload, photo

```
// Creating account
public function store()
{
 $this->validate(request(),[
 all inputs validated...
including ‘photo’ => ‘file|image|max:500’
]);
if(request()->hasFile(‘photo’)){
$path = request()->file(‘photo’)->store(‘profile’, ‘public’);
}
else{
$path = ‘avatar.jpg’;
}

$user = User::create(
[
// all inputs requested...
  including ‘photo’ => $path,
]);

// I log user in and redirect to intended destination
// Success...was able to output profile photo and other things
}


// Now Update account is my problem
public function update(Request $request, User $user-profile)
{
$this->validate($request, [
all inputs validated..
including ‘photo’ => ‘file|image|max:1500
]);

// Genesis of my problem
if (request()->hasFile(‘photo’)){
$path = request()->file(‘photo’)->store(‘profile’, ‘public’);
}
else{
// Please what should I do here....

$user-profile->update(
[
// all inputs requested...
  including ‘photo’ => ???
]);

}
```

The “else” condition of the update method is where my problem lies. Reason: if a user already has a profile photo, if I do the same “else” as during account creation, the ‘avatar.jpg’ then overwrites their initial photo which is not right. Please what can I do to solve this? So when user registers with photo, it’s loaded else avatar is loaded. But when user updates, what do I do? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do same like as store :

```
if (request()->hasFile(‘photo’)){
$path = request()->file(‘photo’)->store(‘profile’, ‘public’);
} else {
   $path = ‘avatar.jpg’;
}
```

Comment: I’m implementing your code now, I’ll update you in a moment how it goes.

Comment: At-STA, your worked. However, something really weird happened. Username, name and email is gone but photo remains, “verified at”, “created at”, “updated at” remains in the database. I can navigate throughout the person’s profile but username, name and email aren’t showing at all (blank). Why is this happening?...note: I added “strip_tags” to the request helper of the inputs before saving to the database. Could this be the reason?

Comment: @cd4success if this is hapeened after update, then may ne you upadted this field with null value

Comment: If you show the full code of update method. Then it will be easy to help you

Comment: @STA....I have edited the code more than 10times but stackoverflow wouldn’t let me submit it...keeps outputting errors.
    ```if (request()->hasFile(‘photo’)){
    $path = request()->file(‘photo’)->store(‘profile’,     ‘public’);
    }
    else{
    request()->except([‘photo’]); // Worked perfect...
    }

    $user-profile->update(
    [
     ‘username’ => strip_tags(request(‘username’)),
    ‘name’ => strip_tags(request(‘name’)),
    ‘email’ => strip_tags(request(‘email’)),
    ‘password’ => Hash::make(request(‘password’)),
    ]);```
    



   
    }```

Comment: Whats the output of dd of request?  `dd($request->all());`

Comment: Everything is is literally gone. When I click on edit profile button, it brings 404 even with the Id in the route. Now I logged the user out and tried reloggging in with old details, results in invalid email and password. I logged in with the updated details, invalid email and password. However, other accounts can successfully log in. Please what has possibly gone wrong?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/217744/discussion-between-sta-and-cd4success).

Answer (score 0):

i dont think you need the else.. if user has uploaded photo then you will need to overwrite users path in the db (which you are doing in the if) otherwise you dont need to and the save() call shouldnt even touch the path field in db

i am assuming your code for creation isnt being triggered somehow when you do the update.

Comment: the update method doesn’t trigger the creation at all.